# How can I compare lots of vectors to each other in CUDA (efficiently)

Tags: c++, optimization, vector, cuda

**Intro**

I'm trying to write a program which compares vectors to each other. I need it to compare each vector to every other vector, and return a vector c, where c[ i ] =  a[ i ] / b[ i ]. So I need a vector C for each pair of vectors in the set.

**Code -- Simplified**

```
__global__
void compare_vectors(*a, *b, *c)  
    { c[ i ]  =  a[ i ] / b[ i ]  }

main()

    for(... all vectors...)  
        compare_vectors <<< grid, block >>> (n, n+1, result)
```

**Problem**

My problem is that doing it this way is slower than doing it on the CPU. Each time I iterate through the for loop, the two comparison vectors are copied to Device memory, and then the result vector is copied back to Host memory.

I want to be able to compare every vector to every other vector, but do it efficiently, and then copy all the results back at once. How can I structure this so that there aren't so many calls to cudaMemcpy ?

**Info**
I'm new to CUDA, so please have grace if this is super obvious.

I've gone through a number of tutorials, and searched around. But all the other examples seem to be comparing two very long vectors, not lots of smaller vectors. I have done a lot of searching and researching, but I can't find a way to do this.

I have around 2,000 vectors to compare. And each vector is compared with every other vector. So ~2,000 ^2 comparisons. Each vector is 100 - 200 floats long.

Thank you @MartinBonner and @platinum95. Drawing it out on a grid really made things more clear.

Comment: Ahem.  `2000²` comparisons, which is a lot - but a *heck* of a lot less than `2000!` (about 10**13000).

Comment: How big *are* your vectors?

Comment: If I understood correctly, for n vectors you have anyways getting n*n c vectors, right? I think you can not make this **c[ i ]  =  a[ i ] / b[ i ]**  got optimized as it has to do one by one division.

Comment: @MartinBonner, each vector is 100 - 200 floats long. Also, its factorial because each vector is compared with every other vector. 
so for vectors a, b, c, d :: its (a vs b) (a vs c) (a vs d) -- (b vs c) (b vs d) -- (c vs d)

Comment: Your problem is far too small to be profitable on the GPU. Don't waste your time

Comment: You have C(n,2) comparisons not n!. For the example you added C(5,2)=10 while 5!=120. So I agree with @talonmies.

Comment: It's neither factorial nor a square, its a combination problem, given by 2000!/(2!(2000-2)!) which is 1999000. 
Also, saying it's not profitable to compute 1999000 floating point divisions of 200-dim vectors sounds untrue.

Comment: @platinum95.  It is not clear if the OP wants to compare a with b and b with a.  I was assuming he was (and was ignoring the fact that a with a is pointless - which means it is actually 2000² - 2000.)

Comment: OP.  To see that it is roughly square, draw a grid.  Label each row with the name of a vector; label each column with the name of the vector.  Each point on the grid is a comparison of a vector with a vector (possibly the same one).  There are n² points on the grid.

Comment: @MartinBonner You're right, I hadn't considered that the function OP was applying isn't reversible. In this case, its 2000P2 which is, as you said, 2000² - 2000. OP seems to have asked for 2000C2, which doesn't seem right since the order of the vectors would change the overall result.

Comment: I've corrected it from 2000! to 2000^2. Thank you MartinBonner and @platinum95. Drawing it out on a grid really made things more clear.

Comment: @talonmies, I still contend that doing it on the GPU is worthwhile. I ran a quick test. I wrote the function as a device function and as a host function. If I compare 2 vectors which are each 1B floats long, it takes 3.4 sec on the CPU and 1.9e-05 sec on the GPU. Problem is, this is with two long vectors, instead of multiple smaller vectors. But I'm really new to CUDA, so if you can expound on your comment from earlier, I'd really appreciate any insight.

Comment: @talonmies: Expanded your comment into an answer.

Comment: @JohnMansell: Your host-side implementation is deficient...

Comment: You should think of a way not to require all the results transferred back to CPU, i.e. all the `c[i]`. What do you need to do with `c[i]` next?

Comment: @SergeRogatch -- The compare() function is actually a little more complicated. I'm using the function to create point and figure charts for stocks, so what I actually need is a binary string of 1's and 0's. Based on if the stock is increasing / decreasing over time relative to another stock. I was trying to simplify my original question as much as possible to only focus on the problem I was having of having to transfer the vectors individually.

Answer (score 4):

You should copy all vectors from CPU to device memory using one `cudaMemcpy` call, and then compute all the divisions in one kernel call. In the kernel you can launch one thread per vector, and then this thread iterates over all the other vectors and computes the division results. If your GPU supports many more than 2000 threads, then you should redesign the algorithm so that a thread iterates not all the other vectors, but only `1/10th` of them, and then the other 9 threads iterate `1/10th` of the vector each.

UPDATE: you don't need to transfer every pair from CPU to GPU. Just create an array with space sufficient to hold all your `N` vectors, each `M` items long, then on CPU copy `N*M` items one after another to this array, then call `cudaMemcpy` to get this array on GPU too.

Comment: Thank you. -- I don't understand what you mean by having the thread iterate over 1/10th of a vector? Can you elaborate? @SergeRogatch

Comment: @JohnMansell, not `1/10th` of a vector, but `1/10th` of all the other vectors that you want to compare the current vectors to.

Comment: When you say "You should copy all vectors from CPU to device memory using one cudaMemcpy call". How can I transfer them all with one call to     cudaMemcpy? Should I concatenate them all into a long vector? one other problem I'm having is that since they're historical stock prices, so not all the vectors are the same length. So I can't automate indexing by a fixed amount. I'd have to also pass in the length of each vector. (If they were all concatenated into one vector)

Comment: Yes, you can concatenate them all into one long vector. Then indeed you would need to pass the lengths to CUDA too.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr: Don't do this on a (discrete) GPU

As @talonmies suggests, this problem is not suitable for using a GPU as a coprocessor.

You see, on Intel platforms, a GPU card does not have the same kind of access to main memory that the CPU does; data must be sent to it over the PCIe bus, whose bandwidth is much lower (typical values: 12 GB/sec vs 30-40 GB/sec for accesses on the CPU). Thus, while the GPU may perform computations faster than the CPU, you only start seeing a benefit if their "density", relative to the amount of data you're working on, is high enough.

In your case, you would transfer a vector for every pair of vectors you're comparing. Even if the GPU were to perform all of its computations instantaneously, in 0 time, it would still be slower than a CPU on this problem due to the need to copy the results back.

(Also, I really doubt you need n*(n-1)/2 vectors, that sounds weird.)

Comment: Thank you for elaborating on why a GPU might not be a good option. I hadn't thought about the transfer speeds. There's actually a lot more math I'll be doing inside the compare function, but I tried to simplify the question down as much as possible. I tried to focus on the main problem of not being able to send lots of small vectors efficiently. Would that change your assertion? I'm still going to see if I can get the total program time down by using the GPU. Right now the CPU takes about 10 min to run 200 vectors in the full version. @einpoklum

Comment: He needs `O(N*N*M)` complexity where `N` is the number of vectors and `M` is the length of a vector. This is a good case for GPU if `N=2000` and `M=200`. He doesn't need to transfer `O(N*N*M)` data as I explained in my answer. He needs to transfer only `O(N*M)` in a single `cudaMemcpy`.

Comment: @SergeRogatch: He said he needed an output vector for every two input vectors, i.e. transferring `N*(N-1)*M/2` elements out. You can't just count the inputs.

Comment: How much computation do you need? Until a few transcendantals it's not worth to store it in memory. Cheaper to recompute on the fly

Comment: @RegisPortalez: It depends. But basically - lots. If it isn't a few dozen per element, don't bother.

Comment: Question was for OP :)